# Could someone check to see if this is grammatically correct?

Tags: gramática

Vivo en una casa en _______. Mi casa tiene alrededor de ocho cuarto. Mi cuarto favorito es el estudio y el comedor. El comedor tiene los mejores altavoces para la música. Me gustan tomar café en el porche. Mi casa tiene cuatro dormitories.  También tiene un comedor, una sala de estar, una sala de mañana y un estudio. Los vecinos son amables y el barrio es tranquilo. En el cuarto de la mañana hay un sofá. A la izquierda del sofá hay una mesita. Mi familia ve tv en esta cuarto. En la tarde me acuesto en mi dormitorio. Mi dormitorio tiene una cama, un armario, un escritorio y television. Estudio en mi dormitorio y ver la televisión.

Comment: It would be better to specify why you are asking. This site is not to do a task for you, but to help you complete it by clarifying any doubt you have. May you, for instance, have gotten this sentence from an automated translation service and you suspect there are errors? When you explain why you cannot complete the task at hand, people may feel more inclined to help you solve it.

Answer (score 2):

> Vivo en una casa en _______.

Correct

> Mi casa tiene alrededor de ocho cuarto.

Uncorrect. "cuarto" (or "habitación" in Spanish from Spain) must be plural: "cuartos" (or "habitaciones"). "Mi casa tiene alrededor de ocho cuartos".

> Mi cuarto favorito es el estudio y el comedor.

Uncorrect. You have 2 favourite rooms, thus the verb, as well as "mi cuarto", must be in plural form: "mis cuartos favoritos" and "son". "Mis cuartos favoritos son el estudio y el comedor".

> El comedor tiene los mejores altavoces para la música.

Correct.

> Me gustan tomar café en el porche.

Uncorrect. "Me gusta" instead of "Me gustan". You can always check by substituing by a pronoun, which would be: "Me gusta esto". Being "esto" a singular pronoun, the verb form must be also singular, thus "Me gusta".

There are times you may use "Me gustan". Example: "Me gustan las manzanas". In this cases, you would make the pronoun substitution as "Me gustan ellas". 
Being "ellas" a plural pronoun (refering to several objects), the verb form is plural too ("gustan").

> Mi casa tiene cuatro dormitories.

Uncorrect. "Dormitories" is English. In Spanish it's "dormitorios" (see the 'o' instead of 'e').

> También tiene un comedor, una sala de estar, una sala de mañana y un
>   estudio.

Correct, I guess. I am from Spain and I don't use "sala de mañana". I guess it may be used in other countries, like Mexico or some latinamerican Spanish-speaking countries. Besides that, the rest of this sentence is correct.

> Los vecinos son amables y el barrio es tranquilo.

Correct.

> En el cuarto de la mañana hay un sofá.

Correct, besides the same doubt than before about "cuarto de la mañana" denomination for a room.

> A la izquierda del sofá hay una mesita.

Correct.

> Mi familia ve tv en esta cuarto.

Uncorrect, 2 errors. In Spanish we say "ve la TV". And "cuarto" is a masculine word, and that needs "este" (masculine) adjective instead of "esta" (for feminine words). The correct sentence would be "Mi familia ve la tv en este cuarto".

> En la tarde me acuesto en mi dormitorio.

Uncorrect. In Spanish we translate "In the afternoon" to "Por la tarde". The most close translation back to English of the Spanish form would be "During the afternoon", if that helps you. This also applies to "por la mañana" ("in the morning"), and "por la noche" ("at night").

> Mi dormitorio tiene una cama, un armario, un escritorio y television.

Correct. Though it would be clear to use "y un televisor", instead of "y televisión". "Televisión" is the service you enjoy. "Televisor" is the object. You watch "televisión" using the object "televisor".

"Televisión" is uncountable, thus not needing "un". You have "televisión" or you don't have it.

"Televisor" is countable, as any object. If you change the sentence to use "televisor", then you should add "un" (number of items).

Correct: "Mi dormitorio tiene una cama, un armario, un escritorio y televisión".

Correct and easier to get: "Mi dormitorio tiene una cama, un armario, un escritorio y un televisor".

Edit: "televisión", not "television".

> Estudio en mi dormitorio y ver la televisión.

Uncorrect. "Ver" is infinitive form. The first person present form is "veo".
The correct sentence would be "Estudio en mi dormitorio y veo la televisión".